# functions being ignored inside async lambda function

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, lambda, amazon-dynamodb, async.js

I'm creating a system that checks player data using an API and then updates to my DynamoDB but appears it stops half way through? as the `Let's scan our players & update stats!` is never shown inside my logs?

```
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {

    var documentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

    var params = {
        TableName: 'games',
        FilterExpression:'updated_at = :updated_at',
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ":updated_at": 0,
        }
    };
    var rows = await documentClient.scan(params).promise();

    let gameAPI = new GameAPI();

    await gameAPI.login().then(function() {

        console.log("We have logged into our game!");

        rows.Items.forEach(function(match) {

            console.log("Let's look at our match! " + match.id);

            var player_params = {
                TableName: 'players',
                FilterExpression:'match_id = :match_id',
                ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                    ":match_id": match.id,
                }
            };

            documentClient.scan(player_params).promise().then(row => {

                console.log("Let's scan our players & update stats!");

            });

        });

    });

};
```

I'm assuming it's something to do with my `async` & `await` functions? could someone point me in the right direction.

Comment: You seem to be mixing your use of `await` and `.then`, is there any reason why?

Comment: @OllysCoding nope, I'm just not very advanced with async stuff; so it's mix & match lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing `await` with `then`.

Try this:

```
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {

    var documentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

    var params = {
        TableName: 'games',
        FilterExpression:'updated_at = :updated_at',
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ":updated_at": 0,
        }
    };
    var rows = await documentClient.scan(params).promise();

    let gameAPI = new GameAPI();

    await gameAPI.login();

    console.log("We have logged into our game!");

    for (let match of rows.Items) {

        console.log("Let's look at our match! " + match.id);

        var player_params = {
            TableName: 'players',
            FilterExpression:'match_id = :match_id',
            ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                ":match_id": match.id,
            }
        };

        let row = await documentClient.scan(player_params).promise();
        console.log("Let's scan our players & update stats!");
    }
};
```

The way `then` works is callback based:

```
documentClient.scan(params).promise().then((rows) => {
    // do something with the rows
});
```

While `await` / `async` works by eliminating the callbacks and enabling you to make your code look synchronous and more readable.

```
const rows = await documentClient.scan(params).promise();
// do something with the rows
```